# Error al filtrar consulta con auth usuario laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb

Estoy intentando filtrar cuentas por empresa. Mas detallado es que solo me filtre las cuentas con el usuario de la empresa logeado.

Esta son las tablas relacionadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo modelo **user.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Notifications\UserResetPassword; 

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    public $table='users';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password','role_id','password','empresa',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    // uno role puede tener varios usuarios (inversa)
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class,'role_id','id');
    }
    
    //relacion uno a muchos (inversa) una empresa puede tener varios usuarios
      public function empresa(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Empresa::class,'empresas_id','id');
    }


    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new UserResetPassword($token));
    }
}
```

Este es el controlador **CuentaController.php** y hasta el momento tengo esta consulta:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cuenta;
use App\DetalleCuenta;
use App\Persona;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
// use App\Http\Requests\CuentaFormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

use Response;

class CuentaController extends Controller
{
    //contructor que permite gestionar el inicio de un usuario para poder ver la ruta de este modelo
    public function __contruct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $empresa = auth()->user()->empresas_id;

        $cuenta = DB::select("select concat(p.nombres,' ',p.apellidos) as cliente, c.idcuenta,  c.saldo, c.total, c.fecha,  u.empresas_id, e.nombre
                        from personas as p, cuentas as c, users as u, empresas as e 
                        where c.cliente_id=p.idpersona
                        and u.$empresa=e.id
                        and c.users_id=u.id
                        and p.tipo_persona='cliente'");

        return view('cuentas.prestamo.index', ["cuenta" => $cuenta]);
    }
```

Este archivo **index.blade.php** es donde pinta las cuentas que quiero filtrar

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section ('contenido')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <h3>
            Listado de Prestamos
            <a href="prestamo/create" class="btn-sm" title="Nuevo prestamo">
                <i class="fa fa-user-plus btn btn-primary"></i>
            </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div id="response">
            @if(Session::has('message'))
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                {{ Session::get('message') }}
            </div>
            @endif
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-stripedtable-bordered table-condensed table-hover" id="grid">
                <thead class="text-center">
                    <th>
                        Factura
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Cliente
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Fecha
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Empresa
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Saldo
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Total
                    </th>
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                </thead>
                <!--Bucle que recorre todas los cuentas-->
                @foreach ($cuenta as $cue)
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td>
                        {{$cue->idcuenta}}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        {{ $cue->cliente}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $cue->fecha}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $cue->nombre}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ $cue->saldo}}
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        {{$cue->total}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="{{URL::action('CuentaController@show',$cue->idcuenta)}}" title="Ver detalles">
                            <i class="fa fa-info btn btn-primary"></i>
                        </a>


                        <a data-target="#modal-delete-{{$cue->idcuenta}}" data-toggle="modal" href="" title="eliminar">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger">
                            </i>
                        </a>

                        {{-- <a href="{{URL::action('AbonoController@exportAbono',$cue->idcuenta)}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-default">
                            Excel
                        </button></a> --}}
                        <a href="{{URL::action('AbonoController@download',$cue->idcuenta)}}" title="exportar en excel">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o btn btn-success"></i></a>
                        <a href="{{URL::action('AbonoController@pdf',$cue->idcuenta)}}" target="_blank" title="mostrar en pdf">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o btn btn-danger"></i></a>
                        <a href="{{URL::action('AbonoController@show',$cue->idcuenta)}}">
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                Ver Abonos
                            </button></a>
                        <a data-target="#modal-abonar-{{$cue->idcuenta}}" data-toggle="modal" href="">
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                                Abonar
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @include('cuentas.abono.create')
                <!--modal de eliminar-->
                @include('cuentas.prestamo.eliminar')
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
@push('script')
<script src="{{asset('js/dataTable.js')}}"></script>
@endpush
```

pero me sale error, lo raro es que si me encuentra el id de la empresa. ya que ingrese con un usuario que tiene el a id de la empresa 1.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No estás desaprovechando las cualidades de Laravel al meter una consulta SQL directa?, sin contar el hecho de que ese *join* aunque parece ser funcional no sigue la sintaxis regular

Comment: @BetaM Tienes razón pero he intentado y ma sale mas errores. Por lo tanto quiero hacerlo de esta forma y despues usar desde eloquent para sacarle provecho.

Comment: @Juanzu de hecho puedes utilizar query builder para hacer dichas consultas

Comment: El error esta en que estas poniendo `u.$empresa` por eso te sale `u.1` (El campo "1" no existe en tu tabla), solo modifica a `u.empresas_id`

Comment: @JuanRivera Con lo que dices me trae todas las cuentas de todas las empresas. Solo quiero que me traiga las cuentas de la empresa del usuario logeado.

Comment: @JuanRivera Me sigue saliendo igual. Porfa lee toda la descripcion de la pregunta.

Comment: @Juanzu esque solo es eso, te voy a ser una respuesta porque simplemente es cambiar un where (Claro si las relaciones estan bien definidas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que estas poniendo u.$empresa por eso te sale u.1 (El campo "1" no existe en tu tabla). Hay otro factor mas que implica esto, para unir tablas es recomendado usar `JOINS` no el `WHERE` por lo que la respuesta completa lo pondre usando eso:

```
$cuenta = DB::table('cuentas as c')
    ->join('personas as p','p.idpersona','=','c.cliente_id')
    ->join('users as u','users.id','=','c.users_id')
    ->join('empresas as e','empresas.id','=','u.empresas_id')
    ->where('p.tipo_persona','cliente')
    ->where('u.empresas_id',$empresa)
    ->select(DB::raw("CONCAT(p.nombres,' ',p.apellidos) AS cliente"),'c.idcuenta','c.saldo','c.total','c.fecha','u.empresas_id','e.nombre')
    ->get();
```

Si las relaciones que mostrastes son correctas, entonces te deberia salir lo que quieres, en tal caso que no quieras utilizar esto te dejo el `RAW`

```
$cuenta = DB::select("
    SELECT CONCAT(p.nombres,' ',p.apellidos) as cliente, c.idcuenta,  c.saldo, c.total, c.fecha,  u.empresas_id, e.nombre
    FROM cuentas 
    INNER JOIN personas AS p ON p.idpersona = cuentas.cliente_id 
    INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id = cuentas.users_id 
    INNER JOIN empresas AS e ON e.id = u.empresas_id 
    WHERE p.tipo_persona = 'cliente' AND u.empresas_id = $empresa");
```

En ambos caso solo es cambiar el `u.empresas_id = $empresa` o `e.id = $empresa`